# Mongo findOne can be run on model and on instance - what is better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, static-methods

Unlike the findOneAndUpdate, the updateOne function can be run on the model as well as on the instance.

After authentication I have the user attached to req so I am currently running the method on my user instance instead of the model because it means less queries to the db since I already have the user object.

I wonder if there is any problem with that (any sync problems or anything i havent thought of?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
      email: String,
      password: String
  ...
});
```

```
const addTolist: async (req, res) => {
        const someId = req.body._id;
        const user = req.user;
        await User.updateOne({
            $push: {
                somethingFromUser: Types.ObjectId(someId)
            }
        });
        try {
            res.send(user)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(422).send(err.message)
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the ID of the user, you can just use updateOne. There will be no problems using updateOne instead of findOneAndUpdate.

You can use findOneAndUpdate in cases where you want to have the data before the update, or even the data after the update. (Cases where you don't want only to update the data, but also, have it).

But you need to pass the ID of the user on the query.

```
User.updateOne({ _id: ... }, updates)
```

But also, you can use findOneAndUpdate as well, it won't run "more queries" as you wrote.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I run the findOneAndUpdate on the model, I would query the db for the user while if I just take the user from req (req.user), I do not need to query the db. Am I not understanding something here?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You always run a query on the model, you can't "run a query" on the user from the request. The only thing is that you can take the ID of the user from the request, which will help you to make the query. Does that make sense?

Comment: So basically, if you want to update the user, you will get the ID of the user from the request, and call " User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user._id }, { name: 'Potato'} ) "